# Guessing a triple of digits by knowing if you got at least one of them right

Tags: contest-math, combinatorial-game-theory, decision-trees

Here is a rephrased version of problem $4$ in BMO $2016$ round $2$. I rephrased to make it clearer and shorter.

> Given is a triple of digits $(a,b,c)$, where $a$, $b$, $c\in\{0,1,\dots,9\}$. Each turn we guess a triple of digits $(m,n,p)$, and instantly know whether the statement
> \[a=m~~\textsf{or}~~b=n~~\textsf{or}~~c=p\]
> is true (however, we are not informed which of the three equalities is (are) true). How many turns will we need at least so that we are guaranteed to determine $(a,b,c)$?

My idea is to first guess $000$, $111$,$\dots$, $999$. If we get a single `true`, then that is $(a,b,c)$.

If we get $2$ `true`s, Wlog they're $111$ and $222$. Then all possibilities are
$$(a,b,c)=\begin{array}{ll}
(1,1,2)&(2,1,1)\\
(1,2,1)&(2,1,2)\\
(1,2,2)&(2,1,1).
\end{array}$$
If we get $3$ `true`s, Wlog they're $111$, $222$ and $333$. Then all possibilities are
$$(a,b,c)=
\begin{array}{lll}
(1,2,3)&(2,3,1)&(3,1,2)\\
(1,3,2)&(3,2,1)&(2,1,3).
\end{array}
$$
I don't know what's the best strategy from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### $13$ guesses are enough

Here is a continuation of your strategy.

"If we get $2$ `true`s, wlog they're $111$ and $222$."

1. Guess $177$. If we get `true`, then $a=1$; otherwise, $a=2$.
2. Guess $717$. If we get `true`, then $b=1$; otherwise, $b=2$.
3. Guess $771$. If we get `true`, then $c=1$; otherwise, $c=2$.

"If we get $3$ `true`s, wlog they're $111$, $222$ and $333$."

1. Guess $177$. If we get `true`, then $a=1$. Go to step 3.
2. Guess $277$. If we get `true`, then $a=2$; otherwise, $a=3$.
3. We know the value of $a$. Wlog, let $a=1$. Guess $727$. If we get `true`, then $b=2$ and $c=3$; otherwise, $b=3$ and $c=2$.

$10$ guesses are used in the question. At most $3$ further guesses are used above. We have used at most $13$ guesses.

#### $13$ guesses are needed in the worst case

Suppose we have a strategy of at most $12$ guesses. Let us apply that strategy.

Consider when we get all `false`s for the first $6$ guesses. There are at most $6$ different $m$'s that appear in the first $6$ guesses. So, there are at least $10-6=4$ different possible values left for $a$. Similarly, there are at least $4$ different possible values left for $b$ and for $c$ respectively. Wlog, suppose $xyz$ where $0\le a,b,c\le3$ is possible still.

Consider the next guess $m_7n_7p_7$. There are 4 cases.

- None of the $m_7,n_7,p_7$ is among $0,1,2,3$. We must get `false` since we know $a,b,c$ are among $0,1,2,3$. We have still at least $4^3=64$ possibilities for $abc$.
- One of $m_7,n_7,p_7$ is among $0,1,2,3$. Wlog, suppose $m_7=0$. It can happen that we get `false`. We are then left with at least $3\times4\times4=48$ possibilities.
- Two of $m_7,n_7,p_7$ are among $0,1,2,3$. Wlog, suppose $m_7=0$ and $n_7=0$. It can happen that we get `false`. We are then left with at least $3\times3\times4=36$ possibilities.
- All of $m_7,n_7,p_7$ are among $0,1,2,3$. Wlog, suppose $m_7=0$ and $n_7=0$ and $p_7=0$. It can happen that we get `True`. We are then left with at least $64-3\times3\times3=37$ possibilities.

In summary, whatever the $7$-th guess is, we could be left with at least $36$ possibilities for $abc$. Since in worst cases after each guess we could be left with at least one half of the current possibilities, after using all remaining $12-7=5$ guesses, we will be left with at least $\lceil\frac{36}{2^5}\rceil=2$ possibilities for $abc$ in the worst cases. That is, that strategy of at most $12$-guesses does not guarantee to determine $abc$.

Comment: The proof of $\ge13$ is very tactful. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome.